# Prevent Regex from devouring optional part of the match

Tags: c#, regex, string

I'v searched extensively but I can't find a simple answer to this and my Regex experience is limited. I'd appreciate a simple solution that is explained, please.

I have a very large string and I need to substitute certain words in it as follows:

Example: wherever you find the string "LINK-ABC" make it "LINK_ABC".

I wrote my Regex Match and Replace strings:
`@"LINK-ABC", @"LINK_ABC"` and it worked.

But there were a couple of things I had not recognized. 
There COULD be words in the file like this:

> LINK-ABC-DEF  LINK-ABC-GHI-JKL ... and so on.

So I get "LINK_ABC-DEF"  etc. (which is NOT what I want; this should have remained intact...)

Once I realized the problem it seemed that what I REALLY wanted was to recognize ONLY the word being matched and leave any cases where it was in combination with something else, unchanged. It seemed to me that if I checked for a space or period on the Match word, that should do it, so...

```
@"LINK-ABC[ |\\.]",@"LINK_ABC"
```

... and now I have stumbled.

Sample string:

> link-xxx link-aaa-sss link-xxx-bbb link-xxx link-xxx.

Match/Replace string:

```
link-xxx[ |\\.],link_xxx
```

Result string:

> link_xxxlink-aaa-sss link-xxx-bbb link_xxxlink_xxx

The replacements are correct, BUT the trailing comma or period has been "devoured" and so the result string is wrong.

Is there a way that I can match so that if it matches on space, the replacement will have a space and if it matches on a period, the replacement will have a period? I s'pose I could do 2 separate matches but I'd like to increase my understanding of Regex and do it more elegantly if it is possible.

Comment: Does it have to be a regex?

Comment: Also, what does this have to do with Python?

Comment: Please put actual code and test string into a formatted block, my ancient eyeballs cannot decode the inline gibberish

Comment: @Mr, Zander: Yes, it needs to be a Regex. As a Programmer, I COULD write my own solution and do the process myself, but I don't see any point in re-inventing the wheel, and I would like to learn more, so I would be interested to see what a Regex-experienced person can come up with. The Python tag was added because I was told that python and C# are very similar and someone in the Python community might be knowledgeable.

Comment: @Mad Myche: here is code:  OUTFile = Regex.Replace(OUTFile, matchstring, fixstr, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Comment: @Mad Myche: here is code:                      '{
                        //sample string...
                        string OUTFILE = "link-xxx link-aaa-sss link-xxx-bbb link-xxx link-xxx.";
                        string matchstring = "link-xxx" + "[ |\\.]";

                        // current Regex...
                        OUTFile = Regex.Replace(OUTFile, matchstring, "link_xxx", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

                    }'
;     (Sorry, I can't get this editor to format it any better...)

Comment: @Morepork edit your original post and add the code there.

Comment: I guess if you want to learn regex, then fine. But a non-regex solution is pretty trivial, and definitely not "re-inventing the wheel". Here is a pretty simple solution with LINQ: `string.Join(" ", input.Split(' ').Select(f => f == "link-xxx" ? "link_xxx" : f));`

Comment: @MrZander:  Thanks for the editing advice. I use LINQ all the time but I don't see it as approriate here. Everything is relative; It would take me 20 minutes to analyze your LINQ statement (Join? Split? why?...) , but for you, it is a "simple solution". Fair enough. Joshua's solution took me 2 minutes to analyze, was explained simply and clearly as I requested, and has added to my store of regex knowledge. Nevertheless, I appreciate your response. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve the behavior you want with "capture groups"

```
var matchstring = @"link-xxx([ \.]|$)";
var fixstr = @"link_xxx$1";
```

The parenthesis around the last part of the `matchstring` will retain whatever matched inside it, and the `$1` in the `fixstr` will substitute whatever was captured by that group.

I've also modified your punctuation section a little bit, presuming you want to replace a match if it happens to be the last word in the input (by adding the `|$`). A `|` inside a character class `[]` is a literal `|` character, so I removed it assuming you don't actually expect that in your input.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly the elegance I was looking for and I have improved my knowledge of regexes. Really appreciate your trouble. Thanks again. I'm not sure how to mark this as an answer but I'll certainly try and upvote your respsonse.

Comment: (OK, managed to figure out upvote and marking as answer but I don't have enough points to be able to upvote you. Thanks again; it is a really nice solution